# zpool stuck in resilvering loop

Tags: debian, storage, zfs, zfsonlinux, zpool

I have the following zpool:

```
    NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    zfspool                     ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                  ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000cca266f3d8ee  ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000cca266f1ae00  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

This morning the host experienced an event (still digging into it. Load was very high and lots of stuff wasn't working, but I could still get into it).

On reboot the host hung during boot waiting on services that relied on data on the above pool.

suspecting an issue with the pool, I removed one of the drives and rebooted again. Host came online this time.

A scrub showed all the data on the existing disk was fine. After that completed, I reinserted the drive that was removed. The drive began resilvering, but gets about 4% through and then restarts.

smartctl shows no issues with either drive (No errors logged, WHEN_FAILED empty).

However, I can't tell which disk is resilvering, and in fact it looks like the pool is fine and doesn't need resilvered at all.

```
errors: No known data errors
root@host1:/var/log# zpool status
  pool: zfspool
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will
        continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
  scan: resilver in progress since Sun Dec  8 12:20:53 2019
        46.7G scanned at 15.6G/s, 45.8G issued at 15.3G/s, 5.11T total
        0B resilvered, 0.87% done, 0 days 00:05:40 to go
config:

        NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        zfspool                     ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x5000cca266f3d8ee  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x5000cca266f1ae00  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

What is the best course to get out of this resilvering loop? Other answers suggest detaching the drive that is being resilvered, but like I said, it doesn't look like either one is.

edit:

zpool events is about 1000 of the following repeated:

```
Dec  8 2019 13:22:12.493980068 sysevent.fs.zfs.resilver_start
        version = 0x0
        class = "sysevent.fs.zfs.resilver_start"
        pool = "zfspool"
        pool_guid = 0x990e3eff72d0c352
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x0
        time = 0x5ded4d64 0x1d7189a4
        eid = 0xf89

Dec  8 2019 13:22:12.493980068 sysevent.fs.zfs.history_event
        version = 0x0
        class = "sysevent.fs.zfs.history_event"
        pool = "zfspool"
        pool_guid = 0x990e3eff72d0c352
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x0
        history_hostname = "host1"
        history_internal_str = "func=2 mintxg=7381953 maxtxg=9049388"
        history_internal_name = "scan setup"
        history_txg = 0x8a192e
        history_time = 0x5ded4d64
        time = 0x5ded4d64 0x1d7189a4
        eid = 0xf8a

Dec  8 2019 13:22:17.485979213 sysevent.fs.zfs.history_event
        version = 0x0
        class = "sysevent.fs.zfs.history_event"
        pool = "zfspool"
        pool_guid = 0x990e3eff72d0c352
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x0
        history_hostname = "host1"
        history_internal_str = "errors=0"
        history_internal_name = "scan aborted, restarting"
        history_txg = 0x8a192f
        history_time = 0x5ded4d69
        time = 0x5ded4d69 0x1cf7744d
        eid = 0xf8b

Dec  8 2019 13:22:17.733979170 sysevent.fs.zfs.history_event
        version = 0x0
        class = "sysevent.fs.zfs.history_event"
        pool = "zfspool"
        pool_guid = 0x990e3eff72d0c352
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x0
        history_hostname = "host1"
        history_internal_str = "errors=0"
        history_internal_name = "starting deferred resilver"
        history_txg = 0x8a192f
        history_time = 0x5ded4d69
        time = 0x5ded4d69 0x2bbfa222
        eid = 0xf8c

Dec  8 2019 13:22:17.733979170 sysevent.fs.zfs.resilver_start
        version = 0x0
        class = "sysevent.fs.zfs.resilver_start"
        pool = "zfspool"
        pool_guid = 0x990e3eff72d0c352
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x0
        time = 0x5ded4d69 0x2bbfa222
        eid = 0xf8d

...
```

Comment: What do you see in `zpool events` ?

Comment: I've updated the main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now resolved.

The following issue on github provided the answer:

https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/9551

The red flag in this case is probably the rapidly looping `"starting deferred resilver"` events as seen in `zpool events -v`

The first suggestion in the link was to disable the zfs-zed service. In my case, it was not enabled to begin with.

The second suggestion was verifying that the zpool had the defer_resilver feature activated. It seems there is a potential issue when a pool is upgraded without the features being enabled that correspond to that upgrade. This pool has moved from multiple machines/operating systems in the past 2 years or so, so it makes sense that it may have been created in an older version of ZFS and is on a newer version of ZFS on the most current host:

```
root@host1:/# zpool get all | grep feature
...
zfspool  feature@resilver_defer         disabled                       local
...
```

After seeing this, I enabled the feature. The github link seemed to suggest this was dangerous, so make sure you have backups.

```
root@host1:/# zpool set feature@resilver_defer=enabled zfspool
```

After that, zpool status showed the resilver progressing further than it had before:

```
root@host1:/# zpool status
  pool: zfspool
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will
        continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
  scan: resilver in progress since Sun Dec  8 13:53:43 2019
        847G scanned at 2.03G/s, 396G issued at 969M/s, 5.11T total
        0B resilvered, 7.56% done, 0 days 01:25:14 to go
config:

        NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        zfspool                     ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x5000cca266f3d8ee  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x5000cca266f1ae00  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```